# jQuery magnify not working in Chrome and Safari but Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Hi I've tried to implement a jquery magnify code on my website. I'm combinding it with a .skrollr javascript for parallax scrolling. It works great in firefox, but doesn't seem to work at all in chrome and safari.

You can see the website at:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209428711/Test-content-site/index.html

The java for the magnify function is

```
<script src="javascripts/prefixfree.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var native_width = 0;
    var native_height = 0;

    $(".magnify").mousemove(function(e){

        if(!native_width && !native_height)
        {

            var image_object = new Image();
            image_object.src = $(".small").attr("src");

            native_width = image_object.width;
            native_height = image_object.height;
        }
        else
        {

            var magnify_offset = $(this).offset();

            var mx = e.pageX - magnify_offset.left;
            var my = e.pageY - magnify_offset.top;

            if(mx < $(this).width() && my < $(this).height() && mx > 0 && my > 0)
            {
                $(".large").fadeIn(100);
            }
            else
            {
                $(".large").fadeOut(100);
            }
            if($(".large").is(":visible"))
            {

                var rx = Math.round(mx/$(".small").width()*native_width - $(".large").width()/2)*-1;
                var ry = Math.round(my/$(".small").height()*native_height - $(".large").height()/2)*-1;
                var bgp = rx + "px " + ry + "px";

                var px = mx - $(".large").width()/2;
                var py = my - $(".large").height()/2;

                $(".large").css({left: px, top: py, backgroundPosition: bgp});
            }
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

All help is very appreciated :)
If you have any questions about the website I can try to answer them.

Peace

Answer (score 0):

try use **mouseover** (change mousemove on mouseover)

Comment: It didn't work. Only made it more unsmooth in firefox. thanks though.